# Can the TFS PowerShell on Target Machines task execute in x86 mode?

Tags: powershell, tfs, x86, biztalk

We have a custom PowerShell script that calls into the BizTalk PowerShell Extensions, that needs to be invoked by a TFS Agent (from Release Management).

The thing is, the BizTalk PowerShell Extensions requires x86 mode, whereas TFS PowerShell on Target Machines task seems to be executing the PowerShell on Target Machines in x64.

Is it possible to solve this by using any of the below approaches?

- By using some undocumented argument to the PowerShell on Target Machines task?
- Have a x64 script invoke the 'real' scripts in x86 mode. I'm not really familiar with PowerShell, and it might be trivial to do, but I would need to figure out how pass my arguments to the x86 script.
- Run the TFS agent service in x86 (e.g. via CorFlags)? I'm not even sure this would even work, and it feels dirty too....

Comment: To run a PowerShell script in 32-bit mode, run it using `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SysWow64 technology allows you to execute 32-bit apps in a 64-bit environment.
On your target machine, please execute PowerShell scripts using the below the app

%SystemRoot%\syswow64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

This would be the 32-bit version of PowerShell.exe and will let you execute your files.

In your batch file, you can make this configuration

Comment: @cordifed Reference this thread: [TFS Build using PowerShell x86 to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24328813/tfs-build-using-powershell-x86-to-run)